# Java read first word in a txt file with multiple string in one line edited*

Tags: java

I have a problem that needs help. My code (below) is a program that helps you with a crossword. It finds all possible solutions from dictionary. If I work with test.txt, you put a stream in for example t*e* and the program works and returns tree and tret. Below you can see my test.txt example. However, I need to make this program to work with a dictionary which contains over 100000 words. Dictionary.txt as shown bellow has 4 words or numbers in 1 row. Any ideas how to read only first word in each line. I would not like a full solution, just some options on how to accomplish this.

test.txt

hourse

house

beer

money

car

tree

tret

ect,..

Dictionary.txt

beer beer tqd 923

tree tree asd 031

trees tree asd 123

..ect

My question is: how can i make my program to read only 1 word in every line.

My code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s;

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("SloveneLexicon.txt"));
          System.out.println("Vnesi besedo, za neznano črko vpiši *.");
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          s=input.nextLine();
        String str;


        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

            if(str.length() == s.length()){
                MatchingWithWildcards wild = new MatchingWithWildcards();

                Collection<String> results = wild.getMatches(str, s);
                if(!results.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(results);
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
}



public class SimpleLongestCommonExtension {

public static int longestCommonExtension(String t1, int i1, String t2, int i2) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = i1; i < t1.length() && i2 < t2.length(); i++, i2++) { 
        if (t1.charAt(i) == t2.charAt(i2))
            res++;
        else
            return res;
    }
    return res;
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class MatchingWithWildcards {

public static Collection<String> getMatches(String t, String p) {
    Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++) {
        int j = 0;
        int h = i;
        int n = p.length();

        while(true){
            int L = SimpleLongestCommonExtension.longestCommonExtension(p, j, t, h);

            if (j + 1 + L == n + 1) {
                result.add(t.substring(i, i + n));
                break;
            }

            if (((j + L) < p.length() && p.charAt(j + L) == '*')
                    || ((h + L) < t.length() && t.charAt(h + L) == '*')) {
                j = j + L + 1;
                h = h + L + 1;
            } else
                break;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Thanks for eny soulution in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily have to split the line because java.util.Scanner's default delimiter is whitespace.

You can just create a new Scanner object within your while statement.

```
Scanner sc2 = null;
try {
    sc2 = new Scanner(new File("translate.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
    boolean b;
    while (b = s2.hasNext()) {
        String s = s2.next();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Referenced from other location.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to fully comprehend what you are asking so I am just replying to your question:

> My question is: how can i make my program to read only 1 word in every line.

1. readLine() like you're already doing.
2. substring() to the first index of empty space. -> word = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' '));

Comment: Disagreed. He's having 1 and 4 words per line in his files. And there is no mention of a bottleneck or better performance needed.

Comment: i have updated so maybe you will understand my problem better

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit unclear whether you want to read every word on all lines, or just read first word and skip the rest.

This code will use a **[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)** to read one word, and then skip the rest of the line by reading the line and not storing it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("Dictionary.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String word = sc.next(); sc.nextLine();
        // Do something with word
    }
}
```

If you want to read every word, just remove **sc.nextLine();**.

Comment: The "sc.nextLine();" will "move on".